# Is using require multiple times on the same symbol idempotent?

Tags: elisp

Is `require` idempotent? i.e. do

```el
(require 'helm)
```

and

```el
(require 'helm)
(require 'helm)
```

end with the same result?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes.  From [Named Features](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Named-Features.html#Named-Features) (emphasis mine):

> A feature name is a symbol that stands for a collection of functions, variables, etc. The file that defines them should provide the feature. Another program that uses them may ensure they are defined by requiring the feature. **This loads the file of definitions if it hasn't been loaded already.**
>
> To require the presence of a feature, call `require` with the feature name as argument. `require` looks in the global variable `features` to see whether the desired feature has been provided already. **If not, it loads the feature from the appropriate file**. This file **should call `provide`** at the top level to **add the feature to `features`**; if it **fails to do so, `require` signals an error**.

Comment: Accepted for quoting the docs.

Comment: Please incorporate the information from Gilles's answer here.  Or, @Gilles, putting this answer into yours would work, too.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, provided that the code in `helm.el` or `helm.elc` respects the rule that it must call `(provide 'helm)`. The call `(provide 'helm)` marks the symbol `helm` as a [loaded feature](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Named-Features.html#Named-Features), and this causes the second call to `(require 'helm)` to do nothing.

If the loaded package does not call `provide` then `require` signals an error, and the feature is not marked as loaded, so a second call to `(require 'helm)` would attempt the loading again (and typically fail again for the same reason).

Comment: +1 Thanks for the extra info. It resolved my confusion after reading the docs.