# Why is it convention to have `(provide <package>)` at the bottom of the file?

Tags: provide

I've been looking through some elisp libraries and most calls to `provide` happen at the end of the file.  In clojure the `ns` is quite similar to `provide`.

I've noticed that putting `provide` at the top of the file makes no difference. Is there a reason for putting it at the end vs at the top?

Comment: or https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/8288 or https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/18638

Comment: i'm talking about 'provide, not 'require

Comment: Ah, so based on your edit you are not asking why libraries contain `(provide <package>)`, but why they contain it *at the bottom* rather than at the top?

Comment: Well I've nominated this to be re-opened, as it turned out not to be the duplicate that it had originally sounded like -- none of the other Q&As address the *actual* question of "why at the *bottom* and not the top?"

Comment: This question ought to be re-opened. The linked question isn't even close to being a duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for putting the `provide` at the end rather than the beginning is the same as the reason for including the comment `;;; <library.el> ends here` at the end of the file:

If it's *not there*, then you know that you don't have the complete file.

The comment is the human-readable version of that, and `(provide 'FEATURE)` is the machine-readable version.

Imagine if you had a truncated copy of `foo.el` with `(provide 'foo)` at the top, and loading it caused errors -- but due to the `provide` Emacs believed it was now fully-loaded, and so subsequent `(require 'foo)` did nothing to fix the problem in that session, even after you installed a corrected copy of the file.

Conversely, if `(provide 'foo)` is the very last form in the file and Emacs processes it, then it is guaranteed that the *entire* file has been loaded as intended.

Comment: FWIW, the purpose of the "ends here" heading is documented under [`(elisp) Library Headers`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Library-Headers.html).

Answer (score 6):

Because it's in the [coding conventions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Coding-Conventions.html), would be one answer. :)

The `provide`/`require`/`features` design is quite simple.  When a package requires a feature it is loaded, but only if it isn't already loaded.  That is determined by checking the list of features found in `features`.

Packages only add their features only once they have finished loading, i.e. only once their features become available to use.  So, they do it last.

More specifically, if the `provide` call is at the beginning you can get unexpected failures where you've done `(require 'foo)` and indeed `(featurep 'foo)` says that `foo` is loaded, yet `(foo-mode 1)` fails saying that `foo-mode` is not defined (because we're still in the process of loading `foo`, actually).

The value of the variable `features` stores the list.  Mine currently has ~300 symbols in it.